# The formal integral of a polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials, commutative-algebra, definition, synthetic-differential-geometry

The formal derivative of a polynomial $p \in R[T]$ over a commutative ring $R$ has a conceptual definition using the ring of dual numbers $R[T][\varepsilon]$:
$$p(T + \varepsilon) = p(T) + p'(T) \varepsilon$$
Is there also a conceptual definition of the formal integral$$\int_0^T p(X) \, dX ~ ?$$
Here $R$ is a commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. Any definition which is more conceptual than the ad hoc definition $\int_0^T X^n \, dX = \frac{1}{n+1} T^{n+1}$ is appreciated. Ideally, the first fundamental theorem of calculus $$\int_0^{T+\varepsilon} p(X) \, dX = \int_0^T p(X) \, dX + p(T) \varepsilon$$ should follow directly from the definition, including $\int_0^0 p(X) \, dX = 0$.

In [synthetic differential geometry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry) and [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis), a similar definition of the derivative works for arbitrary functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. But for integrals, there is just an axiom that they exist and make the first fundamental theorem of calculus true (Bell, *A primer of infinitesimal analysis*, Section 6.1). I would prefer a formula which is similar to the implicit defintion of the derivative, at least for polynomials.

Comment: One obstacle is that formal integration does not work in positive characteristic. To work around this one could use divided power structures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power_structure). I do not know much about them, maybe you find what you want, when you read some survey paper about them.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of divided power structures and - algebras.

Comment: Since the question is somewhat philosophical, I would say that functions are integrated only in undergraduate calculus. In general, you need 1-forms, just as differentiation gives not a function but a 1-form. The case of polynomial ring in one variable may be a red herring.